# Unable to click radio button in Internet explorer using Selenium webdriver

Tags: c#-4.0, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am not able to get the radio button clicked using Selenium web driver.

The html is as follows

```
<input name="PersonalDetails.Paperless" class="input-validation-error" id="Paperless" type="radio" data-val-required="Contract notes selection is required" data-val="true" value="true"/>
```

The code to click is below. It works in Chrome and FireFox but not in Ie

```
driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("label[for='OnlineAndPost']")).Click();
```

Comment: The html <label for="OnlineAndPost"> is placed just before the html mentioned above

Comment: Any errors? What version of IE? What version of IEDriver? What version of Selenium?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It is better to keep it *as simple as possible* for IE, especially when you are dealing with CSS selectors, get the element **by Id**:

```
driver.FindElement(By.Id("Paperless")).Click();
```